# PHP MYSQLI Search Query not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to search query using numeric charter .
But only the charter result I got but I didn't received the numeric charter search result

This Category :

```
2D Animator
3D Animator
VFX Artist
3DCharacter Animator 
RJ
Other Animation
Vocal Artist
```

I didn't get the result.

```
$category = $_REQUEST["category"];

$yyu125_new=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `personal_details` WHERE interest LIKE '%" . $category . "%'");
while($hhf175_new=mysqli_fetch_assoc($yyu125_new)){
    $user_id_new = $hhf175_new["user_id"];
}
```

interest data type text.

So can i get all the category search result.

Comment: Which result you get?

Comment: check  what you are getting in `$yyu125_new`

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your result here: `$user_id_new = $hhf175_new["user_id"];`

so either do something like

```
$user_id_new[] = $hhf175_new["user_id"];
```

or

```
$user_id_new .= $hhf175_new["user_id"];
```

As you don't describe what you really want, it;s hard to actually help you further.

Also: you're wide open to injection, so don't just put that `$category` in there. that's really bad.